# django pick from multiple databases for testing

Tags: django, django-testing, django-database

I have multiple databases defined. This is for test profile, and I want to be able to specify which database to be picked for testing. eg: "python manage.py test -db=mysql"

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'mysql': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mysql_test',
    }
}
```

I went through the django documentation, but i cant find a clear cut way of doing it. One way of getting around this is setting up environment variables, and define both databases as default. Then use the db based on the database type.

please let me know if there is a much better way of doing this.

thanks
Amal

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TEST attribute of DATABASES:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'TEST': {
            'NAME' : 'mysql'
        },
    },
    'mysql': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mysql_test',
    }
}
```

but is there a reason you don't want to use the default test database django creates?